Проблема с overflow:hidden и абсолютным позиционированием в 2-х уровневом меню со слайдером
Есть 2-х уровневое меню. Поскольку пунктов меню много, то я решил сделать меню с прокруткой с помощью slick-slider. Второй уровень меню с абсолютным позиционированием, а для .slick-track установлено overflow:hidden.
Проблема в том, что при клике на пункт меню 1-го уровня должен раскрываться соответствующий 2-й уровень, но его не видно. Как в данном случае совместить overflow и абсолютное позиционирование?
Сайт на вордпрессе. В виджете меню используется Walker_Nav_Menu.
